# Safe to pass the id to update a table?

Tags: php, sql

I want to update a table with the quantity of the products added by users.

I first select all the products with the same code in the table, and I write there id(in the table) in the input name.

client side:

```html
    <input name="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" type="number" min="1" placeholder="Quantity" required/>
```

server side:

```
    <?php
 session_start();
 require __DIR__."/../connectDB.php";
 $memberId = $_SESSION['user_id'];

 foreach ($_POST as $prodId => $quantity) {
   $stmt =$conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_product SET stock = ? WHERE id = ? AND member_id = ?");
     $stmt->bind_param("iii", $quantity, $prodId, $memberId);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->close();
 }
  ?>
```

It works, but is it safe?

Comment: A more commonly used method would be to have a hidden field (with a name like `id`) with the id in it and the quantity field would have a name like `quantity`.  You would then directly reference these field by name.

Comment: how the `id` look like ? it ls incremented number that any people guess or any random number with fixed length ?

Comment: id is incremented in the database automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as safe as any other method of transferring data over the internet but your approach seems a bit odd.

As the comment pointed out, the common method to handle this is to include a *hidden field* to pass along data that should be hidden from the user. You still *have to* validate the data as users can edit hidden inputs too; they just obfuscate it slightly from the common user.

```
<form type="post" ...>    
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" placeholder="Quantity" required >
    ...
</form>

<?php
$productId = $_POST['product_id'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

$query = 'UPDATE product SET quantity = ? WHERE product = ?'
...
```

Edit

If you need to pass through an array of product data from the form, you can use the array syntax `[]` to name your form inputs.

```
<?php

// This array just represents the data coming from your DB.
// Change it to suit.
$products = [
    [
        'id' => 1281,
        'quantity' => 7
    ],
    [
        'id' => 234,
        'quantity' => 2
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3455,
        'quantity' => 25
    ],
    [
        'id' => 64563,
        'quantity' => 84
    ],
    [
        'id' => 235,
        'quantity' => 7
    ],
];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    var_dump($_POST);

    // Handle the form processing here.
}

?>
<form method="post">

    <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="product[<?php echo $product['id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">

        <label for="product[<?php echo $product['id']; ?>]"><?php echo $product['id']; ?>:</label>
        <input type="number" name="product[<?php echo $product['id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>">

        <br>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  'product' => 
    array (size=5)
      1281 => string '52' (length=2)
      234 => string '2' (length=1)
      3455 => string '25' (length=2)
      64563 => string '84' (length=2)
      235 => string '7' (length=1)
  'submit' => string 'Submit' (length=6)
```

You can then loop over this data to create your SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach that I used when I want to accept information from users that I want to be sure that they don't modify anything. I pass a salted MD5 hash of the value that I want to use for reference, and it's important on the application that if the user change affect the execution or login on the code.

HTML FORM

```
<input name="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" type="number" min="1" placeholder="Quantity" required/>
<input name="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>_hash" type="hidden" value="<?php md5($product['id'] . "rand0mC0d3") ?>">
```

Server Side

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require __DIR__."/../connectDB.php";
 $memberId = $_SESSION['user_id'];

foreach ($_POST as $prodId => $quantity) {

   if(is_numeric($propId) and $_POST[$propId . '_hash'] == md5($propId . "rand0mC0d3") ){
     if(is_numeric($quantity)){

        $stmt =$conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_product SET stock = ? WHERE id = ? AND member_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("iii", $quantity, $prodId, $memberId);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
     }else{
        // Value not numeric.
     }


   }
}
?>
```

Note** I wanted to present the concept of passing a salted md5 hash to validate that the value that we want to use to identify the record is not modified. You may need to change it to meet your specific needs. Happy coding.